# Idiot Savant Magic-user

Tags: game-recommendation

I had an idea for a character I'd like to play.  He's an idiot savant Magic-user.  Excellent at anything to do with Magic, but awful at everything else.  Yes, I know this sounds like min-maxing/munchkinning, but this is for a story/character based game, and that doesn't really apply.

The problem I have is this: He would not be Intelligent (in the normal application of the word), Wise, or Socially adept - and most systems base magic off one of those stats.

So, the question - does anyone know a system that would support this kind of character?

(Yes, I know I can fudge something like this, especially as it's a story-based game, but that's not the question I'm asking :P)

Comment: Any system that is skill-based instead of attribute-based will do this. The first that comes to mind is [Fate](http://livingfree.wikidot.com/tri-fold-fate), but there are literally thousands that would do the trick. Unfortunately, that means that this question is too-opened ended for the site because you'll just get a list of the usual fan favourites and with no possible "right" answer. More useful to you would be to collect suggestions by starting a thread at [RPG.net](http://forum.rpg.net) and investigating the ones that intrigue you.

Comment: Yeah, Savage Worlds would do it quite easily as well

Comment: Thanks - "Skill-based systems" is a pretty good answer in my eyes :)

Comment: Sadly, I couldn't make that an answer here that would qualify as useful – [there are 1,600 items on RPGGeek listed under "skill based" games](http://rpggeek.com/rpgmechanic/2094/skill-based-buy-or-gain-skills). That's a lot of reading to do. For recommendations, you either have to have *very* specific requirements that narrow down that 1,600 to a bare few or one (which would make it on-topic here) or you have to accept whatever favourites and opinions people suggest (which is off-topic here, but not on a forum like RPG.net).

Comment: The requirement to make magical power independent of attributes and other skills does rule out a lot of skill-based systems. Fantasy Hero would be a good choice, since you can build magical powers that are totally independent of your other skills and abilities.

Comment: We're not big on list-based questions here. One best answer should be sought and this doesn't lend itself well to that. Once you narrow down your search you might come back and ask if such-and-such a system would support such min/maxing better than another. You might check out GURPS too, I imagine that one would fill the role well.

Comment: Yeah, I would expect toolkit games like HERO and GURPS to excel at the hyper-specialization requirement, but they're less ideal for the story-driven angle. You _can_ streamline the toolkit, but the games are aimed more at the tinkering sort of world-builder than the storytelling kind. Mage is probably a better choice for that.

Comment: See also: [Are game recommendation questions on topic?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic)

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the cases where you'd be well served by **Mage: The Ascension**. In Mage, your aptitude at magick is determined by your level of Arete (a standalone spellweaving stat), your ranks in Spheres (the aspects of the world you manipulate), and the power of your Avatar (the spark in your soul that lets you cast). It doesn't interact with the Attribute and Ability system at all; no brains required!

Comment: Mage: The Awakening would work as well.  There's `Gnosis` for power and the `Arcana` for aspects, but neither one has any ties to mundane abilities.  There are ways to use regular skills to get bigger dice pools, but you don't have to.

Comment: @Bobson That's true, but Awakening relies so much on Rotes that not having access to them is a much bigger hardship. When all your difficulties are 8, you want as many dice as you can muster.

Comment: My characters tend to just go for Gnosis and mostly ignore rotes, so I'm biased.

Answer (score 0):

**Hero System** games allow you to customize how much your magical powers, skills, and ability scores depend on each other. You can layer them like most RPGs, with powers based on skill groups based on related attributes, but you can also build hyper-specialized characters like your magic savant. You can use the **Fantasy Hero** setting for traditional fantasy RP, **Champions** for superhero magicians, or build your own setting with the core system.

The game is pretty crunchy mechanically, and it works best for players who like to tinker and build things. For a story-based game, you'll want to aggressively pursue options for simplifying the game. Preparation helps a lot: Try to build anything you need before it comes up in play, and build your powers so they're quick and simple to use. When you can, take character options that reduce bookkeeping (like endurance tracking).

Also, take advantage of the campaign power limit guidelines, which address most concerns about min-maxing. With a character like this, I actually wouldn't worry about min-maxing so much as teamwork. It's tough for hyper-specialized characters to work with a team, and it's easy for socially maladroit characters to cause friction with other players. Be sure that your GM and fellow players are comfortable with the concept!